# The [data-width] attribute in forms

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make the [data-width] area of a form responsive; however, I can only get it to respond to widths in pixels. Is there a way to right either the HTML or CSS code to reflect a responsive [data-width] area?

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="#" data-colorscheme="light" data-numposts="10" data-width="500" data-order-by="reverse_time"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**`data-width`** referring to the [**Custom Data attribute**](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) in HTML5.  Which is getting processed somewhere in client side scripting.

First check the script file to know how it is getting processed,